# Is the 健 in 健忘 ("forgetful") ironic?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The word 健忘 looks like a contradictio in adiecto: "healthy" + "forget". Am I missing something?

Comment: No. It's a neutral word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

健 in this word means *to be good at, to be skilled at*.

健忘 means *to be good at forgetting* > *forgetful*.

Comment: So, indeed, 健 is ironic here, because forgetting is not a trained skill to be good at?

Comment: @user22495 To Chinese speakers there's no irony because 健's meaning has changed.  It's like "natural makeup" or "accurate stereotype".

Answer (score 0):

健 is not meaning healthy,it means "good at something",like 健谈 means good at talking,康in健康means fine,healthy